# A way to get screen unlock event in android

Tags: java, android, reactjs

I'm developing an application where I want the application to open by itself when there is a lock and unlock event, this is my code, but I can't make it work.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
// A tela foi desligada, inicie seu aplicativo aqui
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("app.ppix.io.mobile");
if (launchIntent != null) {
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
// O usuário desbloqueou o dispositivo, inicie seu aplicativo aqui
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("app.ppix.io.mobile");
if (launchIntent != null) {
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
}
}
}
}
```

and this is my receiver no `AndroidMainifest.xml`

```
 <receiver
    android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
    android:exported="false"> 
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and manifest setup seem correct for listening to screen on/off events and user present (unlock) events.
However, there are a few potential issues to consider:

**Permission**: Make sure you have the necessary permissions declared in your manifest file. You'll need the ACTION_SCREEN_ON, ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, and ACTION_USER_PRESENT permissions.

**Package Name**: Ensure that "app.ppix.io.mobile" is the correct package name for your application. If it's not, you won't be able to launch your app.

**Foreground Service**: Starting from Android 8.0 (API level 26), background execution limits are enforced more strictly. If your app is targeting Android 8.0 or higher, you might need to run your background operations as part of a foreground service to ensure that they are not killed by the system.

**Testing**: Test your app on a real device, as some features related to screen on/off events might not work as expected on emulators.

If you've verified all these points and your app still isn't launching when expected, you might need to debug further by adding log statements in your onReceive() method to see if it's being called and if any errors are occurring.

Create a Service Class: This class will serve as your Foreground Service.

```
   import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class ScreenService extends Service {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1001;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ScreenServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Screen Service")
                .setContentText("Foreground Service is running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add the service declaration to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<service
android:name=".ScreenService"
android:foregroundServiceType="location|dataSync"
android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Start Service from BroadcastReceiver: Modify your BroadcastReceiver to start the Foreground Service when the screen is turned off.

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ScreenService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, your ScreenService will run as a Foreground Service, ensuring that it continues to run even when the app is in the background or the device is locked. Make sure to handle the necessary permissions and notifications for the service to work correctly.

Comment: the permissions are added and the name too, but I didn't understand that very well Foreground Service

Comment: Providing another solution with foreground service

Comment: @VitorAbreu updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: [Generative AI is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)